# Python Play sound using pygame

Tags: python, audio, pygame, wav

I'm trying to get a .wav file to play in my python script.

If I place the sound in the root folder the sound works.

If I move the file and reference it in the script it doesn't and I'm sure my reference is wrong. I have tried 3 ways, but nothing seems to be working.

Attempt 1:

`sounds = os.path.basename ("C:\pager printer\src\pagerprinter\sounds\a.wav")
s = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds")`

Attempt 2:

```
s = pygame.mixer.Sound("C:\pager printer\src\pagerprinter\sounds\a.wav")
```

Attempt 3:

```
sounds = os.path.basename("/pagerprinter/sounds/a.wav")
s = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds")
```

*Attempt 3* script is run in folder src using

```
 c:\pager printer\src>python -m pagerprinter.pagerprinter
```

If I place sound in

```
C:\pager printer\src
```

and run code as

```
s = pygame.mixer.Sound("a.wav")`
```

It works, but I wish to make file neat and tidy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it

```
s = os.path.join('pagerprinter', 'sounds', 'a.wav')
```